# how can i replace spaces and detect the empty data in a line in txt file?

Tags: python

```
NAME         ADDRESS:COUNTRY              AGE                        JOB                 EMAIL
BART         RF_STREET:USA                66                         ENGINEER            BART@YAHOO
KYLE         78_STREET:AUS                                                               KYLE@GOOGLE
WILLIE       6_STREET:AUS                                                                WILLIE@GOOGLE
TRIPP        H_STREET:NZ                  55                         DOCTOR              TRIPP@YAHOO
. 
.
.
```

I have a txt file look like the above. I tried to replace the spaces to `,` and to not remove the empty data like `AGE` & `JOB` for KYLE and WILLIW; hence below is the code

```
input_file = open('A.txt', mode='r')
input_read=input_file.readlines()
input_file.close()

data=[]
for i in input_read:
    data.append(i.split())
```

My output from above code is

```
NAME,ADDRESS:COUNTRY,AGE,JOB,EMAIL
BART,RF_STREET:USA,66,ENGINEER,BART@YAHOO
KYLE,78_STREET:AUS,KYLE@GOOGLE
WILLIE,6_STREET:AUS,WILLIE@GOOGLE
TRIPP,H_STREET:NZ,55,DOCTOR,TRIPP@YAHOO
.
.
.
```

Meanwhile my desired output is

```
NAME,ADDRESS:COUNTRY,AGE,JOB,EMAIL
BART,RF_STREET:USA,66,ENGINEER,BART@YAHOO
KYLE,78_STREET:AUS,,,KYLE@GOOGLE
WILLIE,6_STREET:AUS,,,WILLIE@GOOGLE
TRIPP,H_STREET:NZ,55,DOCTOR,TRIPP@YAHOO
. 
.
.
```

Comment: Is the file tab separated csv file? If that's the case you could just read with csv module without any modification.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun no, it is in txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, splitting all the rows based on the width of the header columns:

```
import re

# ... open file
input_read = input_file.readlines()

colBreaks = [0] + [m.end() for m in re.finditer(r"\s{2,}", input_read[0])]

data = []
for line in input_read:
    data.append([line[i:j].strip() for i, j in zip(colBreaks, colBreaks[1:] + [None])])

print([','.join(result) for result in data])
```

Splitting by `r"\s{2,}"` means headers can have up to 1 space in them and this will still work properly.

Output:

```
['NAME,ADDRESS:COUNTRY,AGE,JOB,EMAIL', 
'BART,RF_STREET:USA,66,ENGINEER,BART@YAHOO', 
'KYLE,78_STREET:AUS,,,KYLE@GOOGLE', 
'WILLIE,6_STREET:AUS,,,WILLIE@GOOGLE', 
'TRIPP,H_STREET:NZ,55,DOCTOR,TRIPP@YAHOO']
```

Due credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734572/1174966) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851479/1174966) for their helpful one-liners.